# EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in Ionic3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

When I command `ionic serve`, I got EvalError.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string
>   as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script
>   in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   gap://ready file://*

I searched about it, but I'm new to coding, so I don't know what to do.

Why this error suddenly occurred and how can I fix this one?

**My ionic version is :**

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.1.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
npm        : 5.0.3
```

Comment: have you read up about [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Comment: right before, I read it thanks to you.
but still I can't figure out how to fix it...

Comment: I have the same problem